What causes the aggregate.data.frame error when running MCA?
I am trying to run an MCA (MCA(widedata.emf.df) in R with FactoMineR on the following dataset, but I get
"Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : arguments must have same length".
Any idea on what might cause this? Here is the str.
str(widedata.emf.df)
'data.frame':   196 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ ID              : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ age             : num  27 37 20 26 34 33 44 27 26 33 ...
 $ gender          : Factor w/ 3 levels "female","male",..: 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ education       : Factor w/ 3 levels "bac-uni","mast-phd-uni",..: 1 1 3 3 2 2 3 2 1 2 ...
 $ subj.knowl.quant: Factor w/ 3 levels "Q1","Q2","Q3": 1 2 1 3 3 1 1 1 3 2 ...
 $ obj.knowl.quant : Factor w/ 3 levels "Q1","Q2","Q3": 2 2 3 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ electric        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ antenna         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ signal          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

There are more factors looking like the three at the end of this code (electric, antenna, signal), but they all have the same structure (binary coded) so I deleted them for space sake.
The dataset has no NA.
I see online that this is a common R error when not specifying the variables correctly. However I do not understand what causes it here. Here is the traceback output.
traceback()
5: stop("arguments must have same length")
4: aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...)
3: aggregate.default(res.mca$var$contrib/100, by = list(factor(variable)), 
       FUN = sum)
2: aggregate(res.mca$var$contrib/100, by = list(factor(variable)), 
       FUN = sum)
1: MCA(widedata.emf.df)```


That error often means that either the vector you're trying to aggregate (here, res.mca$var$contrib/100) or your grouping variable (factor(variable)) changed size in an unexpected way. In my experience it is usually because one or the other vector is empty because of an upstream process.
FactoMineR::MCA doesn't look like an easy function (or at least I'm not clever enough to spot the problem immediately) so I would clone the read-only repo from GitHub, add a browser() before that line in MCA, build & reinstall, and then inspect the elements manually to see which part of that line is causing the issue, and work backwards from there.

Thank you for your answer. unfortunately my debuging skills are very limited. For now I solved the issue by removing the numeric variable age, but I still do not understand why the issue happened in the first place.
